# Is there any way to profit from PvP?

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

I'm playing Bloons Monkey City in pacifist mode.  I'm level 18 in my primary city.

I'd like to understand the rewards for PvP.  The main point of PvP seems to be attacking people to try to steal their money, but since they're doing the same to you it seems like no net gain in money.

I've heard there are experience rewards for defending in PvP.  Can I leave pacifist mode and then just sit in my city defending against attacks?  If I have 0 honor, will all the attacks be easy to defend against?  Is that a good source of experience?

Is there any other way to get a net gain of resources from participating in PvP?

Comment: I play the mobile version, and I run PvP for the Bloonstones - I get 5 from the first attack per day, I think 3 every subsequent attack.  If the other player doesn't respond to the attack (which they rarely do) I get 2 more for free.  Very easy way to get premium currency!

Comment: @agent86 How much actual city cash do you get from those attacks?  How often do you get attacked, and how often can you fight the attack off?  If you make your comment an answer I will happily upvote it.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the mobile version at least, MvM is an excellent way to make Bloonstones.  The first attack per day earns you 5 stones, and subsequent attacks give you 3.  There's also a 2 stone bonus for attacks you send that win (or are ignored by the enemy).

I rarely if ever defend against attacks, and it seems like a good 90%+ of other players ignore them as well.  In the mobile version, there's no XP gain for winning, it's just cash, honor, and Bloontonium, which refills automatically.  The only reason I care about honor is for achievements.

Cash win/loss wise, I've got so much cash that I don't even pay attention to it.   My capacity is around 200k gold, and I have 1.8m.  Aside from retrying boss fights, there's nothing to spend it on.  I believe in general if I attack as often as my Bloontonium is full, I'll end up profiting.

Honor-wise, staying at low honor will probably end up pitting you against weaker opponents, although I think I generally gain honor by attacking as often as I can and losing every attack.  Currently I'm at around 10k honor from this strategy.  The losses are so slight compared to the gains that it's hard to stay low.

Answer (score 0):

This answer discusses the flash version.

Defending against PvP attacks is not a good idea.  Every incoming attack is attached to an uncaptured tile next to your base; when you do the defense, you defend on the map for that tile.  If you win the defense, you capture the tile.  The rewards for winning the defense seem to just be the rewards for capturing the tile.  If you want to capture tiles, it's much simpler (and lower-risk) to do that directly, rather than in response to PvP attacks.

Deliberately losing to PvP attacks is very low-risk.  Once every 24 hours, you spend all your money, then lose to each attack in turn.  If you don't have money, the attacks will wreck your buildings, but the most damage you can ever take is to have your super monkey villas wrecked for four hours.  If you lose your battles before logging off for the day, the damage won't be a problem for you.

(I imagine the situation changes once you buy all your upgrades, as agent86 has done.  I'm not there yet.)

Making PvP attacks is occasionally valuable, because sometimes your opponent won't use the above strategy for losing to PvP attacks, and they'll accidentally lose a lot of money to you.  My city is level 27; out of my last ten attacks, I had the following results: won 18450, won 2000, lost, lost, won 2000, won 11550, won 6871, won 2000, lost, won 22410.

Note that these attack wins give you money even if your banks are full.  If you need to build a very expensive item, you may not be able to hold enough cash to buy it normally, but getting a PvP win at the right time could let you buy it.

When choosing a target for an attack, the random matcher will often match you against someone you can't send a max-power attack against (because your tanks don't hold that much bloontonium).  One workaround is to friend a bunch of random people and then use the "attack friend" button to choose a target that is low enough level that you can attack them for the max power they can receive.  I don't usually do this, though -- it takes time to scroll through my friends list to find a good target, and attack power doesn't seem to be very correlated with cash from attacking.

In conclusion, PvP is a decent way to make money, but it does not produce experience or bloonstones, beyond what you'd normally get for capturing tiles.  The main cost to PvP is the cost (both in money and in city tiles) of building all the stuff needed to send attacks.